# Read a list of files using Dask

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dataframe, dask

I found that Dask can read several `csv` files this way:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('myfiles.*.csv')  # doctest: +SKIP
```

But what if I want to load not all but some of them:

```
my_files = ['file1.csv', 'file3.csv','file7.csv']
df = dd.read_csv(my_files)
```

But that doesn't work:

> ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 2 elements, new values
>   have 3 elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My error was that some of my `csv` files had different number of columns.
Reading a list of files to one dataframe works next way:

to get `dask.dataframe`:

```
df = dd.read_csv(["small1.csv", "small2.csv"])
print(df.shape)
print(type(df))
```

Output:

```
(Delayed('int-863f32f2-a8c3-4ac9-b31f-0186541c347c'), 3) 
<class 'dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame'>
```

To get `pandas.dataframe`:

```
df = dd.read_csv(["small1.csv", "small2.csv"])
df = df.compute()
print(df.shape)
print(type(df))
```

Output:

```
(11000, 3)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```